# How to set theme for indeterministic ProgressBar in ProgressDialog in Android

Tags: android, themes, progress-bar, progressdialog, customdialog

I have an Android (developed on A2.2) app with following theme defined:

```
<style name="ProgressBar"> parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_medium</item>
</style>
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@drawable/bgr_alert</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar</item>
</style>
```

where 'progress_medium' drawable is my custom (blue) progressbar and 'bgr_alert' is custom (white) background.

When I show the dialog (application's theme is 'MyTheme')

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
  progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
  return progressDialog;
}
```

the dialog that shows up contains custom background (white), but the indeterministic progressBar is not visible.

On the other hand, if I set the progress drawable manually:

```
progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_medium));
```

everything is perfect - custom background and custom progress drawable.

Any hint, why the progressBar drawable is not set implicitly by theme theme?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I've got my answer. The problem is that Android's progress_dialog.xml layout contains explicit style for ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@android:id/progress"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="10000"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dip" />
```

So I have to either do the manual setting (as described above) or do completely custom dialog.

Comment: Mark your answer as correct! Thanks you saved me sometime looking for why this was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was really hard to find the solution.

I think your are using, in your definition of **MyTheme** android:background:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
   <item name="android:background">@color/white_color</item>
   .....
   <item name=".....">value</item>
</style>
```

I've made the same mistake, we should use **android:windowBackground** and give it a color or a drawable. This way the dialogs will not be affected by your theme background.

Let me know if this solution works for you!